# Chrome Div regions not expanding to full width?

Tags: html, css

I did a search around and couldn't find this already asked but I'm sure it must have come up before and I can't find it. So sorry if this is a duplicate question in advance.

I have a simple site layout I'm working on. I noticed today in chrome that 2 of the div regions don't expand fully to the width. In firefox and IE they do expand fully. The 2 offending div regions do contain tables. Could this be the cause?

Heres a picture, Chrome on the right, gaps on the top div and bottom footer div:

[image: Chrome Gaps]

This is the CSS for the two regions:

```
.topbar{
    margin: 0;  <---Added this in a hope to fix it.
    width:76%;
    height: 34px;
    background-image:url('img/topImgBg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-right: 12%; 
    color:white;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:right;
}

.footer{
    height:15%;
    width:76%;
    padding-left:12%;
    padding-right:12%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#A1A1A1', endColorstr='#ffffff'); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#A1A1A1), to(#ffffff)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #A1A1A1,  #ffffff);
}
```

And the body CSS:

```
html, body {    
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    min-width:1024px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

TIA

Comment: Is `topImgBg.png` 1 pixel wide?

Comment: I don't know what should happen in this case, but the browser might not repeat it again horizontally if doing so would overflow the window. What happens if you use a 1 pixel image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `width` set to `76%`. And `padding` on left and right also in percentages. I think this is a percentage rounding difference in browsers.

You may find that the gap changes if you change the browser width in very small increments.

What if you didn't specify any `width` and just left the `padding` as you have it now. That should work.

Comment: Yep that does the trick, just specifying the padding and not the width. Thanks for the help. I've learnt something new and hopefully this will be useful for others looking for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the parent container to

```
display: table;
```

and the child blocks to

```
display: table-cell;
```

chrome will calculate percentages correctly (as long as they add up to 100%). for example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="forty">asdf
    <li class="forty">asdf
    <li class="twenty">asdf
</ul>

<style>
    ul { display: table; width: 100%; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    li.forty { display: table-cell; width: 40%; }
    li.twenty { display: table-cell; width: 20%; }
</style>
```